# Ubuntu 12.04.1 (64bit) only recognizes 7.8gb of RAM from 8gb RAM

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, ram

I know that is a little diference between 7.8gb to 8gb, but still a diference, why Ubuntu dont recognizes all of my RAM? I had the same case with my 32 bit Pc, 3gb RAM and Ubuntu only recognized 2.98gb, again, it is a little direfence but I wish to know why that happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On Ubuntu, which applications use binary file size units, and which ones use decimal units?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/222656/on-ubuntu-which-applications-use-binary-file-size-units-and-which-ones-use-dec)

Comment: There's nothing wrong, it all comes down to this: IEC Units-7.8GiB, SI Units-8GB.

Comment: What application in Ubuntu shows this? Please provide the output of `free -m` from the terminal to have a non-ambiguous representation.

Answer (score 2):

It could be either that the system is using IEC Units instead of SI units, **or** that your Graphics card reserves space for its personal use.

For example I have 2 GB Ram installed, but only 1.7GB is usable because 256MB are dedicated to my Graphics Card.

Comment: 0.2MB is not RAM taken for an IGP.. they usually use 256MB or more.

Comment: I just noted both situations. I know it's probably the first.

Comment: well, I just wanted to know if this was normal, and I see that it is, thank you for the comments.