# Real size of folder?

Tags: filesystem, files, du

When I run `du -hs Folder` in the terminal I get: **118M**

When I run `du -s Folder` in the terminal I get: **120664M**

When I run `du -h Folder` in the terminal I get: **118m**

When I find the size through the file explorer (right click -> properties) I get: **65.5M**

So, which is the correct one and why does this happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second output, `du -s Folder` is in kilobytes not megabytes. That is the default output for `du`. To convert to MB divide by 1024: 120664/1024 = 117.8359375, with the `h` flag this gets rounded up to 118MB.

You can also view the size of the folder in Bytes with `du -sb Folder`.

The **du** utility gives you the amount that is actually used by the disk. The value you are seeing in the file explorer is the apparent size. These are not the same as explained in `man du`:

```
   --apparent-size
          print  apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due
          to holes in (`sparse') files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
```

If you use `--apparent-size` option in `du` it will give you the same value that you see in the file explorer.

As for why size on disk is different than the size of all the files, see this response: [Why is disk usage greater than the size of all files on it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234913/why-is-disk-usage-greater-than-the-size-of-all-files-on-it)

Comment: In my case, `du -sh --apparent-size` shows `182M`, `du -sh` shows `190M` and size from the explorer gives `137.8M`. What am I missing?