# File size stated is bigger than expected

Tags: filesystem

The Ubuntu file system says my file is 5.2MB.
When I right click on the file I can see the file size in bytes is stated as 5,154,017.

[image: File properties screen grab]

Doing some simple maths we can calculate that in MB:

5154017 / 1024 = 5033.219726562KB

5033.219726562 / 1024 = 4.915253639MB

How does Ubuntu determine the 'rounded' value of the file size displayed in the files dialog? - This question may not be Ubuntu specific.

It does not appear to be using normal rounding e.g. half up which would display as 5MB.

Comment: Related: [What file size units do applications on Ubuntu use?](https://askubuntu.com/q/222649/301745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu always makes the distinction between base-10 prefixes (kilo, mega, giga, etc) and base-2 prefixes (kibi, mebi, gibi, etc). That is, you will never see mebibytes (mis)labeled as megabytes. So in this case, 5.154 MB rounds to 5.2 MB.

See [Units Policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy) on the wiki for more details.

Comment: In context of file sizes in an operating system, "MB" and the term "megabyte" has pretty much exclusively meant 1024x1024 bytes throughout computing history.  While I can appreciate the logic and "correctness" of the push to switch to 1000x1000 instead, it's taking it a bit far to label all previous usage of "MB" and "megabyte" as 1024x1024 bytes in computing history as incorrect.  Remember that "mebibyte" is a much more recent term for that quantity and acts as a disambiguator because "megabyte" has meant both.

Comment: @thomasrutter Hey, don't look at me, I didn't write the Units Policy ;)

Comment: I don't disagree with the units policy, I disagree that everyone who has used MB/megabytes to refer to 1024x1024 has misused the term.  The units policy itself acknowledges how this is standard practice in a lot of contexts.

Comment: @thomasrutter Oh, I see what you mean. I wrote "(mis)labeled" because in Ubuntu, the words are strictly defined.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses the
[bytes > kilobytes > megabytes system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix)
(1000 bytes = 1 kilobytes, 1000 kilobytes = 1 megabytes)
instead of the
[bytes > kibibytes > mebibytes system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)
(1024 bytes = 1 kibibytes, 1024 kibibytes = 1 mebibytes).

So 5154017 bytes = 5.154017 megabytes ≈ 5.2 megabytes.