# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit without DVD or USB, just CD

Tags: 14.04, cd-image

Is there a way to create a single or multi cd Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit install disk from Windows 7 instead of a dvd or usb? I have an older Dell pentium4 machine w/ no dvd and it can't boot to usb. Currently running Debian (classic), but I would like to try Ubuntu. I'm a novice to Linux.

Comment: Why it can not boot from USB? did you try with bootable USB stick? and also fo boot foom USB you have to make `USB external devices` as first boot in your BIOS boot order.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/137588/brasero-says-it-wont-burn-the-cd-because-the-file-is-too-big-whats-going-on

Answer (score 1):

You can use the minimal installation CD.  This is an Ubuntu installer CD image that is small enough to fit on a regular CD.

It uses a text-based installer similar to Debian's installation CDs, and it fetches most of the packages over the internet which is why the installer CD image can be so small.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Normally I wouldn't recommend it to a novice, only because it's slightly less user friendly than the regular installer, but if you managed to get Debian installed, then you should be able to achieve this.