# The latest LUBUNTU image will not fit on a CD. What files can be deleted to make it fit?

Tags: lubuntu, iso, cd

I am trying to get lubuntu on to an older dell laptop that will not boot from usb.  The computer is only equipped with a cd drive.  The CD image is 705 mb.  Real cute. that makes it not a cd image as it is too large.  What files can be safely deleted from this cd image to make it fit on a CD?????

Comment: Why a CD and not a USB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Brasero says it won't burn the CD because the file is too big, what's going on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137588/brasero-says-it-wont-burn-the-cd-because-the-file-is-too-big-whats-going-on)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're aware of this, but the 14.04 is the newest LTS (Long-Term Support) version that's recommended for most users. Non-LTS versions are only supported for 9 months. The latest LTS image, Lubuntu 14.04LTS, fits on a 700MB CD.

It is unfortunate that the Lubuntu 14.10 desktop image is 705MB. I'm not sure, but you might be able to use overburn to make it fit on a 700MB disk. Otherwise, you can get a bigger CD, which do exist. You can get 800MB CDs and 900MB CDs. Or you could use a DVD if your computer can read them.

If you really do require 14.10 and none of the above can be used, then you'll want to get the Alternate installer. This uses a text-based "GUI", but otherwise simple to use although slightly less beautiful. It also requires a lot less resources, so it's useful for old computers with little RAM. Because it installs the system as packages, however, it is slower than using the Desktop installer.

You can get the Alternate installer for 14.10 here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.10/release/

But again; I recommend 14.04LTS for most users.

Comment: I just went to download the 14.04lts.  703mb.  Same boat.

Comment: It is reported as being 683MB. Did you use this link? (I'm on mobile connection, so I can't test). http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: you can burn the iso on a normal "so called" 700MB CD! - they are wrong labeled (difference between [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) and [decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) prefix): it have to be 700[MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) --> so on a "normal 700MiB CD" around [734MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Optical_discs) really fit on it!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy your answer should be more visible.. I think you should make it a full blown answer rather than a comment. Thanks a lot! big relief

Comment: maybe i'll post a full answer in future since there is also a possibility to boot from USB via [Plop Boot Manager](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/index.html) even if it is not supported (for the case a iso really don't fit on a CD)...!

Answer (score 0):

You should burn lubuntu 14.4 (694 mb) to a CD then upgrade to 16.4 from there.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/
(second section of the link)

Comment: Please write the instructions in your answer, link only answers end up removed.

Answer (score 0):

If your CD-ROM doesn't support dvd disks too, you could try a 800MB CD. Here is how: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/453525-how-to-burn-to-800mb-cdr/. Anyway, 800MB are very rare, if not extinct. Maybe you can manage buying one from the internet. Or buy an old dvd-rom with dvd writing capability.